# Refreshing blazor component after updating data in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I am using Blazor WebAassembly with C# on Visual Studio. The data is locally connected to Microsoft SQL database

I have Bills.razor and Bills.razor.cs. The page shows upcoming payments and payments history. There is a "make payment" button for upcoming payments which mark the payment as paid, and it successfully works as I can see after I refresh the page from browser manually (it gets moved to the payments history section). How do I make it refresh automatically when I click on "make payment" button? Why does my code not refresh?

In Bills.razor, I have `<button @onclick="@(() => MakePayment(b))">Make Payment</button>` where b is a certain Bill.

This calls the function in Bills.razor.cs

```
private async void MakePayment(Bill b)
        {
            await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/make-payment", b);
            //await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
            //StateHasChanged();
            //BillsHist = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Bill>>("api/get-bills-history");
        }
```

I have tried the ones that are commented out but they don't make it refresh. The api call updates the selected bill in Bills table.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to force the component to update after the payment is made is to call the StateHasChanged() method, which will cause the component to re-render.

Here's an updated version of the MakePayment method that should force the component to update:

```
private async void MakePayment(Bill b)
{
    await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/make-payment", b);
    await Task.Delay(100); // Wait for a brief moment to ensure the payment has been processed
    BillsHist = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Bill>>("api/get-bills-history");
    StateHasChanged(); // Force the component to re-render
}
```

a better version should return `Task` instead of `void`

```
private async Task MakePayment(Bill b)
{
    await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/make-payment", b);
    await Task.Delay(100); // Wait for a brief moment to ensure the payment has been processed
    BillsHist = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Bill>>("api/get-bills-history");
    StateHasChanged(); // Force the component to re-render
}
```

Comment: Note that the MakePayment method should return a Task instead of void, as async void methods can cause issues with exception handling and other aspects of asynchronous programming.

Comment: Ohhh thank you so much!
I actually had to do StateHasChanged() after updating BillsHist.